# Cross-account access to AWS Glue Data Catalog via Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is it possible to directly access AWS Glue Data Catalog of Account *B* via the Athena interface of Account *A*?

Comment: If these are totally separate accounts, it would be a serious security hole if one was accessible from the other.

Comment: Those security holes can be restricted to certain tables with IAM roles, can't they?

Answer (score 5):

I was just trying to resolve this same issue in my own setup, but then stumbled across this bummer (the last bullet under `Cross-Account Access Limitations` on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/cross-account-access.html)):

```
Cross-account access to the Data Catalog is not supported when using an AWS Glue crawler, Amazon Athena, or Amazon Redshift.
```

So it sounds like even with the cross-account access that is possible today, they won't naturally replicate through those services (including the asked about Athena).

That said, I was able to set up cross-account access to the AWS Glue Data Catalog in a way that allowed me to use Account A to pull all relevant info about Data Catalog objects from Account B. I can update my answer to incorporate how far I got, if you want, but a hacky method that might solve this question would be to set up the cross-account access that is possible today then run a recurring Lambda function that replicates over all the relevant metadata in the Data Catalog from Account B to Account A so users in Account A can view that within Account A's AWS Glue Data Catalog. I'm not sure whether Athena specifically would work in that setup, as I know it requires `PutObject` access when it queries data in S3 (which could be solved via the appropriate S3 bucket policies, but that'd be another cross-account permissions thing to manage).

Let me know whether you'd like to see those details on what cross-account stuff I was able to get working.

Answer (score 4):

AWS has started supporting this using Lambda, please follow below link
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/cross-account-aws-glue-data-catalog-access-with-amazon-athena/

Comment: This has some limitations .. Lambda can support only 6MB of payload.. When athena query cross account via lambda, resultset is passed back via lambda to athena. Since lambda support only 6MB of payload, this approach fails.

Comment: The Lambda is used for accessing the metadata only (the AWS Glue Data Catalog). The results of the queries are still managed by Athena itself. The 6MB limitation on Lambda payload mentioned by @SKB applies to metadata retrieved from the Data Catalog. This limit may still be hit, but for many use cases, it is high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since May 2021 it is [now possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-athena-adds-built-in-support-for-cross-account-aws-glue-data-catalogs/) to register a data catalog from a different account in Amazon Athena, see the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-sources-glue-cross-account.html).

Athena Query Engine v2 is required though and there are some other [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/security-iam-cross-account-glue-catalog-access.html#security-iam-cross-account-glue-catalog-access-considerations-and-limitations).

Comment: but as 27th May, it does not support cloudFormation to do that. Either you can use UI or Java application to create an Athena Data Catalog that Points to other account.