# How to access AWS Athena tables from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-iam

I have 2 AWS accounts: Account1, and Account2. I have some data stored in S3 in Account1, and I registered that data into an Athena table in Account1. Now, I would like to access the same Athena table from Account2. I realize that I could create an Athena table in Account2 to query data in Account1, but ideally I would like to keep all the tables under Account1.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a [limitation][1] Athena does not support cross-account access to the AWS Glue Data Catalog.

[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html

Comment: @alexgbelov did you find any answer for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since May 2021 it is [now possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-athena-adds-built-in-support-for-cross-account-aws-glue-data-catalogs/) to register a data catalog from a different account in Amazon Athena, see the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-sources-glue-cross-account.html).

Athena Query Engine v2 is required though and there are some other [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/security-iam-cross-account-glue-catalog-access.html#security-iam-cross-account-glue-catalog-access-considerations-and-limitations).

Answer (score 1):

As of today, it seems possible only by deploying in Account2 (the account you want to query from) a Lambda with the proper cross-account permissions to access the data catalog in Account1.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549650/4830306) and the [associated post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/cross-account-aws-glue-data-catalog-access-with-amazon-athena/) on AWS blog.